# Customizing push notification

Tags: ios

Can I have a push notification from APNS which does not contain any badge,alert or sound but app will be notified.

For MDM server the 3rd party server used to wake up the device via APNS. But there is no alert to the user like badge, alert or sound. So how to achieve it.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

It's doable using MobileSubstrate and a jailbroken app, and creating a socket to your server.
I have a sockets class available for download, [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25258177/personal/SocketLib.zip).

[Here](http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.com/2009/10/how-to-compile-mobilesubstrate.html) is a reference to how to create a mobile substrate addon, which you can use for reference.

Code:

```
extern "C" void ExampleHookInitialize() {
    Socket *socketToServer = [Socket boundTCPSocketWithAddress:[SocketAddress addressWithPort:SOME_PORT domain:DOMAIN_INET ip:SOME_IP] error:NULL];
    [socketToServer connect:[SocketAddress addressWithPort:SERVER_PORT domain:DOMAIN_INET ip:IP_OF_MY_SERVER]];

    while (true)
    {
         // reads the first 1024 bytes (1 KB) to socketData
         NSData *socketData = [socketToServer read:1024];

         // do something with data
    }
}
```

Note that this may be better done on separate thread, and my sockets library was compiled with ARC.

Comment: This app is meant for normal devices not jail broken.

Comment: Then, you cannot do anything from there. The APNS doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 0):

Except under a handful of very specific circumstances, apps aren't allowed to run in the background on iOS. Even if you do send a notification that isn't a badge/sound/alert your app wouldn't be able to do anything with it unless it was already running.

So no, it's not possible.

Comment: Tanks for ur quick response. So let's say my app is always in foreground or some how i have achieved to keep it running in background always,For that scenario is it possible to send an notification to my app through APNS which will not contain anything (alert, sound or badge) but could be some very short msg.Another query is How to register for such notifications.

Comment: @user1151028 Looking at [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1) on APNS payloads, you should be able to send some small amount of data in JSON format.